# How to draw a line joining two sides of a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line joining two sides of each triangle. The line should join AB to BC. However, I am finding it difficult. So, could you please, help me? Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (60:3) coordinate (B) (3,0) coordinate (C);
        \draw[thick,path picture={
            \foreach \X in {A,B,C}
            {\draw[line width=0.4pt] (\X);}}]   
        (A) node[left]{$A$} to[bend right=12] 
        (B) node[above right]{$B$} to[bend right=15] 
        (C) node[right]{$C$} to[bend right=20] cycle;
        %   \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {$<180^\circ$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Triangle in a CAT(0) space}
        \label{fig:tri1}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{0.05cm}%\hfill
    \hspace{-0.12cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (60:3) coordinate (B) (3,0) coordinate (C);
    \draw [thick,path picture={
        \foreach \X in {A,B,C}
        {\draw[line width=0.4pt] (\X);}}] (A) node[left]{$A$} (B) node[above right]{$B$}    (C) node[right]{$C$} (0,0) --  (60:3) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Triangle in an Euclidean space}
    \label{fig:tri2}
    \end{minipage}%\hspace{0.05cm}%\hfill
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which points on both lines should be connected?

Comment: @Zarko: As I stated, I only want to join AB to BC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add named `coordinate`s in the middle of path segments, e.g. with `\draw (A) -- coordinate(b) (C);` or `\draw (A) to[bend left] coordinate(b) (C);` there will be a coordinate named `b` halfway between the coordinates `A` and `C`.

To add a label node next to a coordinate you can use the `label` option, for example ``\draw (A) -- coordinate[label=left:foo] (b) (C);`

By the way, in the code below I reduced the width of the `minipage`s a bit, and changed the horizontal space to `\hfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (60:3) coordinate (B) (3,0) coordinate (C);
        \draw[thick]   
        (A) node[left]{$A$} to[bend right=12] coordinate[label=left:$a$] (a) 
        (B) node[above right]{$B$} to[bend right=15] coordinate[label=right:$b$] (b)
        (C) node[right]{$C$} to[bend right=20] coordinate (c) cycle;
        %   \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {$<180^\circ$};

        \draw (a) -- (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Triangle in a CAT(0) space}
        \label{fig:tri1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (60:3) coordinate (B) (3,0) coordinate (C);
    \draw [thick] 
          (A) node[left]{$A$} -- coordinate[label=left:$a$] (a)
          (B) node[above right]{$B$} -- coordinate[label=right:$b$] (b)
          (C) node[right]{$C$} -- coordinate (c)
          cycle;
     \draw (a) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Triangle in an Euclidean space}
    \label{fig:tri2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but as I stated earlier, I only want to join AB to BC

Comment: Can you please, adjust this?

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal Sorry, but just use `\draw (a) -- (b);` instead of `\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer. However, what if I want to label each of those points newly joined to the triangles' sides? Plus one!

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal You already know one way to do that, you've done it for the points `A`, `B` and `C`. A slightly quicker way is to use a `label` for the `coordinate`, e.g. `coordinate[label=left:$a$] (a)` instead of `coordinate (a)`.

Comment: The perfect answer I needed. Thanks and God bless you!